# Ubuntu 19.10 Centralise icons on dash/dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock, dash-to-dock

I have moved the Dash/Dock from the left of the screen to the bottom. I would now like the icons centralised on it. I have installed dconf-editor but can't see an option for it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see the option, because it is not there. The only way to locate the icons in the center of the screen, is to turn off the `extend-height` option. This shortens the dock to the space needed for the current icons, and places it in the center.

With the `extend-height` option on, the dock covers the whole width of the screen edge, but icons are placed on top (vertical modes) or on the left (horizontal modes). It is (currently?) not possible to center icons in this mode.

A workaround to achieve the visual effect you are after could be to modify a wallpaper so the bottom has a bar in the color and with the width of your dock. That way, it would appear as if icons are centered on a dock that is entirely stretched.

Comment: OK, I'll use Plank instead.

Comment: Does plank allow to stretch the dock over the entire screen *and* have the icons in a central position? Then indeed, this is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use Plank....